# Laravel 8 return blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In controller;

```
 public function list_of_approved_policies(){
    
      dd("I am here");
      die(); 
    }
```

In route

```
Route::get('/listofapprovedpolicies','MerchantDashboardController@list_of_approved_policies');
```

When I calling /listofapprovepolicies Laravel return just white blank page. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to change the route's declared sintax to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MerchantDashboardController;
.....

Route::get('/listofapprovedpolicies',[MerchantDashboardController::class, 'list_of_approved_policies')->name('policies_list');
```

and in controller make the dump

```
public function list_of_approved_policies()
{
    dd('dumped');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it